# SQL - I want to do the opposite of this code

Tags: sql, database, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum

FROM Database1.dbo.tblCustomers
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWebUsers on tblWebUsers.SiteNum = Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum

WHERE **tblWebUsers.ID = '4'**
```

This returns all sitenums relating to a webuser id but how do i do the opposite? i.e. return all site numbers not associated to a webuser id - I have tried not in (4) but it just returns all webusers site numbers that don't have an id ... I want it from database1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not clear what the opposite would be (we don't have any sample data and expected results to work with, and only you can see your actual database), but I'd note that having `tblWebUsers.ID = '4'` in your where clause is forcing the left join to become an inner join.

This may be closer to what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum

FROM Database1.dbo.tblCustomers
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWebUsers on
      tblWebUsers.SiteNum = Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum and
      tblWebUsers.ID = '4'
```

Or more editable into the final form you're seeking.

---

In fact, I *think* that this is what you're wanting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum

FROM Database1.dbo.tblCustomers
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWebUsers on
      tblWebUsers.SiteNum = Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum and
      tblWebUsers.ID = '4'
WHERE
    tblWebUsers.ID is null
```

That is, you want to find rows from `tblCustomers` which *do not* have a row in `tblWebUsers` with `ID` equal to 4. But again, it would be better if you could more clearly explain what you're trying to achieve, hopefully with sample data and expected results.

Comment: This just returns all data - tblwebusers.id there is no id relating to this and the customer table and sitenum is not the primary key - this is probably the problem

Comment: @user1099719 - is my update any closer? You can tell people are struggling to understand what you're looking for, can't you?

Comment: Yes the update returns all sitenums in the customer table that don't have user id to the sitenum in the webuser table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum
    FROM Database1.dbo.tblCustomers 
    WHERE tblWebUsers.ID NOT IN (SELECT tblWebUsers.ID FROM Database1.dbo.tblUsers)
```

Comment: If you want all site numbers **not** associated to a user ID, that means the site numbers are, indeed, NULL. Why are you putting '4' in the WHERE syntax?

Comment: Well I want to pass a parameter through code and I was testing it

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum
FROM Database1.dbo.tblCustomers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tblWebUsers 
    WHERE tblWebUsers.SiteNum = Database1.dbo.tblCustomers.SiteNum 
        AND tblWebUsers.ID = @tblWebUsersID
)
```

Where @tblWebUsersID is your parameter.